# How to stop fan running always on Asus P8P67LE motherboard with ATI Radeon HD6900

Tags: ati, asus, fan

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I'm not sure if it is the CPU (i7) fan or the video card fan.

I've tried using lm-sensors & fancontrol

```
sudo sensors-detect

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `w83627ehf':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `Nuvoton NCT6776F Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
# Chip drivers
coretemp  
w83627ehf
```

Like many people, I'm also getting error:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Here is the output of sensors:

```
# sensors
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +71.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 1:         +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 2:         +43.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 3:         +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
```

I'm hoping some-one has already solved this for my configuration because this seems to be a problem for many people and there are many different suggestions.

Comment: I've opened up the case and rebooted multiple times, and although it is difficult to tell, I'm pretty sure now it is the fan on the ATI Radeon HD6970 that is the problem, not the CPU fan or 2 chasis fans.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this myself because I couldn't find any other answers to this in Ask Ubuntu although a work around is mentioned in at least several Ubuntu bug reports.

Refer [Bug 748080](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/748080) + [Bug 563156](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/563156)

Unfortunately bug 748080 has now been marked as **Won't Fix** as it was for Ubuntu 11.04.

First I tried setting **power_method** to  **dynpm** (dynamic):

```
sudo echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

dynpm seems to keep temperature around 64C but there is screen flickering when video card works hard
(eg scrolling fast thru a document) and you can hear fan rev'ing up & down. Very annoying...

The best work around for me so far is to set **power_method** back to **profile**, then set **power_profile** to **low**

```
sudo echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
sudo echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

Fan is much quieter now (still makes small noise) and no flickering or fan rev'ing.
'sensors' says temperature is 51C although I've got no confidence this is accurate.

To make permanent put into the /etc/rc.local :

```
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

**NOTE:**
BEWARE It's possible that forcing power_profile to low could be allowing the display adaptor to overheat. Time will tell...